# can not get ref through FlatList

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I tried to get each item's ref but it always null

Is this correct way?

I hope someone help me to solve...

```
.....
  const _contents = React.useRef([]);
  const _flatlist = React.useRef(null);

  itemList.forEach((_, index) => {
    console.log(React.createRef())
    _contents.current[index] =  React.createRef()
  });

  const renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
    <Item ref={_contents[index]}/>
  )

  return (
    <FlatList
      ref={_flatlist}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      data={itemList}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
    />
  );
........
```

Comment: Not a good way to create ref of each item. Create ref of the list and handle item through it

Comment: So How do get each ref through renderItem correctly?

Comment: Why you need each item of ref?

Comment: To make slider component

Comment: @Naoya What are you doing using these refs?